# How to execute function with console

Tags: node.js

I want to write some command with some args (for example /add 5 5 and it will print 10) in console when program is already running. How should I do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351521/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-node-js

Comment: I don't mean to launch the app with some arguments, but to write a command during program execution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to read from console is already explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20087094/898435), so I'll just show you how to parse those lines.

Example approach is to create object with references to your functions, and then call them by name, after parsing input string.

My example uses [Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) and [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) which need running script in strict mode ( `"use strict";` ).

Example's code:

```python
"use strict";

var funs = {};

funs.add = function add (x, y) {
  if( x === undefined || y === undefined ) {
    console.log("Not enough arguments for add!");
    return;
  }
  console.log("Result:", (+x) + (+y));
}

function parseInput(input) {
  if( input.charAt(0) === "/" ) {
    let tmp = input.substring(1);
    tmp = tmp.split(" ");
    let command = tmp[0];
    let args = tmp.slice(1);

    let fun = funs[command];

    if ( fun === undefined ) {
      console.log(command, "command is not defined!");
      return;
    }
    fun(...args);
  }
}

parseInput("/add 5 6");
```

Answer (score 1):

The following `npm` packages could help you a lot, and their docs are very great to start with:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/comman
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/prompt