# How to pass variable to function and set new value to it?

Tags: javascript, function

I find it very hard to explain or search for this problem, so I'm asking Stack Overflow.

I'm asking user for user-input in the terminal several times and want to make a function out of it. A function that takes a question and a variable, and the input should be added to the variable.

This is my code:

```
var name = 'hello',
    age = '11'

var readline = require('readline');
// var rl = readline.createInterface(process.stdin, process.stdout);
var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});
var getInput = function(inputVariable, question, cb) {
  rl.question(question, function(answer) {
    inputVariable = answer;
    rl.close();
    cb();
  });
}

var askForName = function() {
  console.log(1,age, name);
  getInput(name, "What's your name? ", askForAge);
}
var askForAge = function() {
  console.log(2,age, name);
  getInput(age, "How old are you? ", printIt);
}
var printIt = function() {
  console.log("Hello, " + name);
  console.log(".. and " + age + " old.");
}

askForName();
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for.

Comment: Don't pass to function variable you want to set. Instead use return value from the function. Or if you absolutely must pass variable - pass an object and set its properties inside of function.

Comment: maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20086849/how-to-read-from-stdin-line-by-line-in-node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In node.js applications, this is usually solved using either a callback chain or promises.

Using callbacks, you could write your code like this:

```
var getInput = function(question, cb) {
  rl.question(question, function(answer) {
    // Don't set the variable, but return value to callback
    rl.close();
    cb(answer);
  });
}

// ask* take a callback which they call with the value
var askForName = function(cb) {
  getInput("What's your name? ", cb);
}
var askForAge = function(cb) {
  getInput("How old are you? ", cb);
}
// printIt takes the values as parameters
var printIt = function(name, age) {
  console.log("Hello, " + name);
  console.log(".. and " + age + " old.");
}

// Now ask for name and age and store them as local variables
// inside callbacks
askForName(function(name) {
  askForAge(function(age) {
    printIt(name, age);
  });
});
```

I added comments to explain the changes. Basically, the values are only being passed between callbacks, never exposed to another scope.

Comment: The first two console log statements would fail if the age / name variables aren't defined at the top.  Make sure to remove the statements, or note that they won't be accurate.

Comment: @TbWill4321 Thanks, I forgot about them.

Comment: @still_learning I like a lot your answer. This approach is the best, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass a variable to a function, changing the *reference* to it will not affect the original variable.  You can *modify* the variable's properties. However, that shouldn't be used as the main method of passing around variables.

A common way of passing a response from an asynchronous process is to use a callback function.  You've almost got it:

```
var getInput = function( question, cb ) {
  rl.question(question, function(answer) {
    rl.close();
    cb(answer);
  });
}

var askForName = function( cb ) {
  getInput("What's your name? ", cb);
}
var askForAge = function( cb ) {
  getInput("How old are you? ", cb);
}
var printIt = function( name, age ) {
  console.log("Hello, " + name);
  console.log(".. and " + age + " old.");
}

askForName(function(name) {
  askForAge(function(age) {
    printIt( name, age );
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, only certain things are passed by `reference` - they are `objects` and `arrays`.  all other primitive types (strings, integers, etc.) are not.

With that being said, there are a number of ways for you to get what you are after here.. especially since `age` and `name` are essentially `globals` (at least in the current scope of things)

One way is to just have the `getInput()` method `return` the value you want, and then assign that to your `global` var.  Another would be to just write `setter` methods for each `global` you're wanting to change.  There are others, but those are the 2 easiest..

anyways, the following would resolve your issue:

```
var name = 'hello',
    age = '11'

var readline = require('readline');
// var rl = readline.createInterface(process.stdin, process.stdout);
var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});
var getInput = function(inputVariable, question, cb) {
  rl.question(question, function(answer) {
    if( inputVariable === 'name' ) {
        name = answer;
    } else if( inputVariable === 'age' ){
        age = answer;
    }
    rl.close();
    cb();
  });
}

var askForName = function() {
  console.log(1,age, name);
  getInput('name', "What's your name? ", askForAge);
}
var askForAge = function() {
  console.log(2,age, name);
  getInput('age', "How old are you? ", printIt);
}
var printIt = function() {
  console.log("Hello, " + name);
  console.log(".. and " + age + " old.");
}

askForName();
```

now, there are more elegant ways of doing this.  for instance, you could create a `map`, you could change the if statements to a `switch`, you could have `getInput` return a string via the `callback`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

you can use an `Object` instead a primitive value, because **objects** are passed by reference, meaning the memory address of the original object will be affected.

In the following example, by leveraging that feature in objects, I also used the **[`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)** method, to set the execution context of the function (that is useful in case the `answers` variable is not global.

```
//outer variable
var answers = {
  name: "hello",
  age: "11"
};

var readline = require('readline');
// var rl = readline.createInterface(process.stdin, process.stdout);
var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

function getInput (propertyName, question, cb) {
  var answers = this; //gets the context associated to the current function
  rl.question(question, function(answer) {
    answers[propertyName] = answer;
    rl.close();
    cb();
  });
}

function askForName () {
  console.log(1, answers);
  //sets the execution context of getInput
  getInput.call(answers, "name", "What's your name? ", askForAge);
}

function askForAge () {
  console.log(2, answers);
  //sets the execution context of getInput
  getInput.call(answers, "age", "How old are you? ", printIt);
}

function printIt () {
  console.log("Hello, " + answers.name);
  console.log(".. and " + answers.age + " old.");
}
```