# How can I take input from keyboard in Javascript programming language?

Tags: javascript, node.js, scanf

I know Js can be used in nodejs as a server scripting language.It can also be used to manipulate data in a html file,but how can we use a scanf/cin option in JS?

Answer (score 0):

In depends on the environment in which javascript is running, if it is nodejs you can easily find a way to read from standard input from nodejs documentation, However if it browser, then only way of input is from the input fields.

Answer (score -1):

You can use readline api or process api for it with node.js. Refer the node.js documentation for more info.

Comment: Can you paste the code and refer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20086849/how-to-read-from-stdin-line-by-line-in-node