# How do you pipe some values to a node evaluated script?

Tags: node.js, bash, sh

I can escape the cli arguments node consumers with `--` and have `hi` be my arg that's used in the text node evaluates, but I can't do the same piping a value.

```
j at MBP in ~
$ node -e 'console.log(">", process.argv[1])' -- hi
> hi
```

The piping here in bash should just take stdout and add it as an arg for the command it gets piped right?

```
j at MBP in ~
$ echo hi | node -e 'console.log(">", process.argv[1])' --
> undefined
```

Comment: You need to read from standard input, not argv.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pipe `|` feeds the output from the `echo` command into `stdin` on the `node` command.  You'll need to use the `readline` module to read in a fluid way from stdin -- there are other ways too, but this is easy enough.  (stolen from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20086849/how-to-read-from-stdin-line-by-line-in-node)).

```
var readline = require('readline');
var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
  terminal: false
});

rl.on('line', function(line){
    console.log(line);
})
```

If you want to use the output from echo as a command line parameter, you need to use backticks:

```
node -e 'console.log(">", process.argv[1])' -- `echo hi`
```

or a subshell:

```
node -e 'console.log(">", process.argv[1])' -- $(echo hi)
```

Comment: This is fine for small amount of text... but when I pipe in a large file (say `cat file.txt`) I get the error 'Argument list too long'. I have tried reading the line but it just hangs (I think waiting for some user input). Is there a method to pipe in large data without user prompt?

Comment: Yes, it's called reading a file.  The typical way would be to have a command line argument like `--moreargs @somefile.txt` or using a configuration file to store common parameters `--config /some/config.json`

Comment: I found that instead of using the argument and sub-shell, I can just pipe it from another program and have node.js read line. For example: `command1 | node -e "var fs = require('fs'); /* get fs module */ var data = fs.readFileSync(0, 'utf-8'); /* read from stdin */`