# How to read only a single line from command line in Node.js, similar to Python's `input` or C++'s `std::getline`?

Tags: javascript, node.js, input, command-line

In Node, there does not seem to be a straight-forward way to easily get a single line from the commandline.

Solutions I have found so far:

1. `readline` module's `on('line', callback)` [[*](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_event_line)]
2. `readline`'s `question(q, callback)` [[*](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_rl_question_query_callback)]
3. `process.stdin.pipe(require('split')()).on('data', callback)` [[*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20091680)]
4. `fs.readFileSync(0).toString` [[*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45486670)]

But all of the above are not nearly as straight forward as [python's `input`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_input.asp) or C++'s [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). (Also, I could not get option (4) to work on Windows.)

The `readline` approach is probably the best, but the fact that it requires the use of `callbacks` is frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping the dedicated `readline` module's function(s) in promises is probably still the best approach. Here we emulate Python's `input` and C++'s `getline` functionality.

NOTE that node event's don't only have an `on` function, but also a [`once`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_once_eventname_listener) function.

```js
// input.js

const readline = require('readline');

const cmd = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});


/**
 * Emulate Python's `input` function.
 */
export async function input(prompt) {
  return new Promise(r => cmd.question(prompt, r));
}

/**
 * Emulate C++'s `getline` function.
 */
export async function getline() {
  return new Promise(r => cmd.once('line', r));
}
```

```js
// main.js

async function main() {
  const x = await input('What is x?');
  console.log('x is', x);

  console.log('What is y?');
  const y = await getline();
  console.log('y is', y);
}

main();
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because NodeJs aims for Asynchronous IO.

Getting a single line involves reading a stream (*commonly the keyboard input stream*) and waiting for a particular delimiter (*commonly the newline character `\n`*).

This is against NodeJs policy of providing Asynchronous IO, and thus there is no synchronous (simple) getline call available.

The @Doomi's answer gives you the *illusion* of a synchronous fetch (like C++'s `std::getline`), but by the time the the line is fetched, there could be other code running (*another listener /callback function that you have registered elsewhere*)