# Automate Node.js CLI program from shell script

Tags: node.js, shell, sh

I and trying to execute a node.js CLI program which takes an input from user to decide the next step.

I am able to start the program by
`node index.js`
after this I want to send `1` as input. Is there a way I can give input to my node.js program.

My dumb brain came up with following script

```
--Script.sh--
node index.js
1
2
```

which obviously didn't work.

Comment: listen on stdin

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20086849/how-to-read-from-stdin-line-by-line-in-node

Comment: @王仁宏 **I do not want to change node.js program** I this achievable via shell script only

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would work?

Create an answers.txt file with each input on its own line:

```
first
second
```

then run the command like this:
`node index.js < answers.txt`

The `<` will redirect input to the specified file instead of stdin.

Comment: Hey @flet I tried it seems to  work a little bit Node.js got input ```first``` but did not waited for ```second``` got terminated after first input. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
#!/bin/dash
echo "Type something or 'q' to quit and press Enter!"
while read user_input; do
    if [ "$user_input" = 'q' ]; then
        break
    else
        echo "You've typed: ""$user_input"
        # do something
        # node index.js "$user_input"
    fi
done
```