# How to get the contents of textarea to a separate JavaScript-file?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

Is it possible to somehow get the contents of a textarea element to a separate JavaScript file without inseting the JavaScript file into the HTML code? I cannot insert the JavaScript file into the HTML file, because MathSteps won't work in a browser.

Here's the JavaSript file:

```js
question = getTextareaContentsById("question")

const mathsteps = require('mathsteps');
const steps = mathsteps.solveEquation(question);

steps.forEach(step => {
    console.log("before change:");
    console.log(step.oldEquation.ascii());
    console.log("change:");
    console.log(step.changeType);
    console.log("after change:");
    console.log(step.newEquation.ascii());
    console.log("# of substeps:");
    console.log(step.substeps.length);
});
```

And here's the HTML file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Step By Step Calculator</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto">
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
            margin: 10px;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: white;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .container {
            display: block;
        }
        #question {
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        #submit-button {
            width: 10vw;
            margin: 0 auto;
            align-items: center;
            text-align: center;
            display: block;
        }
        #steps {
            text-align: center;
            margin-left: 50%;
            transform: translateX(-50%);
            background-color: aquamarine;
            width: 200px;
        }
        #steps:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: antiquewhite;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h2 id='header'>Enter a math problem:</h2>
    <textarea id="question" cols="90" rows="1"></textarea>
    <p>Steps:</p>
    <div id="steps-container">
        {% for line in stdout_lines %}
        <p class="steps">{{ line | safe }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the Python file, too:
'''

```
# main.py
from flask import Flask, render_template
import subprocess

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    result = subprocess.run(["/usr/bin/node", "mathsteps.js"], capture_output=True, text=True)
    stdout = result.stdout
    # Erota tulosteet rivinvaihdolla
    stdout_lines = stdout.split("\n")

    return render_template("home.html", stdout_lines=stdout_lines)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port='3002')
```

'''

I'm very new to JS, CSS and HTML, so bear with me. Thanks!

Comment: You could quite easily take the content from the textarea and generate a dynamic download with that content which you could then save - what you do with it after that is up to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key points that you need to focus on here are that:

- You have an HTTP server (written in Python) which a web browser can request an HTML document from.
- You want, I assume, the user of the browser to type some data into that textarea and send it to the server for processing
- You want to process it with a JavaScript library

---

## Getting the data from the browser to the server

Start with an [introductory forms tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Your_first_form) which covers [sending form data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data).

- Put the textarea in a [form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) (with an action pointing to a URL on your server)
- Give the [textarea a name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea)
- Add a [submit button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)

## Process the submitted data

- Create [a route](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/quickstart/#routing) for the URL
- [Read the form data](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/quickstart/#accessing-request-data)

## Pass it to the Node program

**Your Python program doesn't seem to have any reason to be in Python. Your project appears to revolve around a Node.js library. Consider rewriting your HTTP server using Node.js with the [express library](https://expressjs.com/). This will be less fuss than shelling out to run an external process and passing the data to it.**

If you are sticking to Python:

- Write the collected data to [stdin in your subprocess call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475290/how-do-i-write-to-a-python-subprocess-stdin)
- Change the Node.js program to [read from STDIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20086849/how-to-read-from-stdin-line-by-line-in-node).

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed reply! This is very helpful!